# mount and /proc/mounts showing different outputs

Tags: linux, mount, slackware

0

I have the following line in my /etc/fstab on three of my slackware servers:

```
tmpfs            /dev/shm         tmpfs       rw,nodev,nosuid,noexec 0   0
```

All three show the mount options correctly in /proc/mounts:

```
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
```

Two of them show the correct options with the mount command:

```
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nodev,nosuid,noexec)
```

The third one shows different options with the mount command:

```
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
```

The only difference is the third one is at runlevel 4 while the other two are at runlevel 3. Any ideas on why the third one is showing two different mount options and which one is the correct one?

Comment: That's most likely a question for https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record: the other copy is [on U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/671333/108618).